# exclude subview from UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a subview and a superview. The superview has an UITapGestureRecognizer attached to it.

```
UIView *superview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0, 0, 320, 480);
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(100, 100, 100, 100);
UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(handleTap);
superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[superview addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[self addSubview:superview];
[superview addSubview:subview];
```

The recognizer is fired inside the subview as well, is there a way to exclude the recognizer from the subview?

I know this question has been asked before but I didn't find a good answer to it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use gesture recognizer delegate to limit area where it can recognise touches similar to this example:

```
recognizer.delegate = self;
...

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:superview];
    return !CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, touchPoint);
}
```

Note that you need to keep reference to your parent and child view (make them instance variables?) to be able to use them in delegate method

Answer (score 3):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if(touch.view == yourSubview)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Thanks : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19603248/552488

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3, you can use `view.contains(point)` instead of `CGRectContainsPoint`.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if yourSubview.frame.contains(touch.location(in: view)) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```