# UITapGestureRecognizer on UIView and Its Subview Respond Together When Subview Is Tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

`UITapGestureRecognizer` is applied to both `UIImageView` and its subview (`UITextView`). However, when I tap on subview, the receiver becomes subview and its parent view (i.e. `UIImageView` + `UITextView`). It should however be only **subview** because that was the one I tapped. I was assuming nested gestures would react first but apparently parent receives the fist tap and then it goes to child.

So, there are different solutions out there for various scenarios (not similar to mine but rather buttons inside scroll view conflict). How can I easily fix my issue without possible subclassing and for iOS 6+ support? I tried delaying touch on start for `UIGestureRecognizer` on `UIImageView` and I tried setting `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` - all with no luck.

Comment: mind sharing some code please. How do you add gestures ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following code:

conform the <`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`> to your class.

set `yourGesture.delegate = self`;

then add this delegate Method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    // return YES (the default) to allow the gesture recognizer to examine the touch object, NO to prevent the gesture recognizer from seeing this touch object.
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass: [UITextView class]] == YES)] {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Hope it will solve your issue. Enjoy Coding..!!!!

Comment: some comments about full picture of shouldReceiveTouch: it was processed before everything(gesture recognizing, touches event and so on), and the subview will be called first.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what is it supposed to do. 
View hierarchy is like a tree structure and its traversal during a touch gesture starts from the root node. It is very likely for your parent view to receive gesture first and then its subviews. The traversal skips the nodes for which

> userInteractionEnabled = NO.

since, you don't have any code I can't help you to play with this flag. A more general solution is to always set gesture only for your parentView and in the gesture delegates check the coordinates if it belongs to any one of the subview  and if yes then call your gesture method for your subview. 
Not a clean approach but works. !!

Comment: My problem was the touch gesture always gone to the superview and skipped the subview. Turning the flag to YES (or true in swift) saved my life

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the UIGestureRecognizer delegate methods and apply the correct policy to the gesture, when multiple gesture are recognized