# Triggering UITapGestureRecognizers from overlapping Views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have one main view and 4 subviews of the mainview they all have their UITapGestureRecognizer, when I tap on one subview how can it be triggered both views. Example below,

[image: view hierarchy]

if I tap to subview 1 desired log would be:

```
subview1 is clicked
MainView is clicked
```

My Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let mainGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mainGestureActivated))

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(mainGesture)

    let subGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(subViewGestureActivated))

    self.subview1.addGestureRecognizer(subGesture)


}

@objc func mainGestureActivated(){
    print("MainView Clicked")
}

@objc func subViewGestureActivated(){
    print("Subview Clicked")
}
```

it prints only subview clicked! Is it possible to trigger both gestureRecognizers since main is encapsulating other.

Comment: main view will be called anyway , so consider it in your logic

Comment: Show the code you have tried already.

Comment: @Magnas I added my code if it helps but the question is really simple actually I want to get chain reaction of the views and subviews when one tapGesture triggered in the subview. Now I'm thinking maybe there's another way of getting this chain reaction other than using adding TapGesture recognizers to the views.

Comment: @Sh_Khan mainView's gesture is not called if I click to the subviews. Only subviews is called.

Comment: Your question might be simple but Stackoverflow is only for asking for help with your code. It isn’t for asking general “how do I do something?” type questions. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks for the advice @Magnas although it's a very simple question yes I agree sometimes it's better to see the code.

Comment: I think you’re going to have to implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and use the protocol methods that come with that. I’m not at my computer now but this question outlines a possible approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592622/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-uiview-and-its-subview-respond-together-when-subview-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your VC, and then implement the delegate func of `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`. Inside the function, you should detect if the `gestureRecognizer`, and the `otherGestureRecognizer` are the wants you want, and if so, you should allow them to work simultaneously,

- Conform to delegate, and Declare gesture recognizers outside of `viewDidLoad` (because you need to access them in the delegate method later.)

  `var mainGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
   var subGestureRecognizer =  UITapGestureRecognizer()`
- Initialize your recognizers, and set your VC as their delegate:

  ```
  mainGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mainGestureActivated))
  subGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(subViewGestureActivated))
  mainGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
  subGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
  ```
- Implement the delegate function mentioned above to allow simultaneous recognition for subView and mainView:

  ```
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
      if gestureRecognizer == subGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == mainGestureRecognizer {
          return true
      }

      return false
  }
  ```

And if you want it to work for 4 different subviews, then you should check with else if statements inside the delegate method.

Comment: thanks, it turns out '''shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith''' is what I needed.