# UITapGestureRecognizer: Modal View is overlapped by another view

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, gesture, overlap

I have a UIViewController that I show as a `modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`.

This over-the-context view (`self.view`) has `backgroundColor = .clear` and a subview called `content`.

`content` is full bounds width and half bounds height with a white background.

I've added UITapGestureRecognizer to `self.view` but I cannot tell to not fire the tap action when tapping the overlapping view (`content`).

Any idea on how to only trigger the action when the user taps on the view, not on the subview?

Answer (score 1):

You need to conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and then implement `shouldReceive touch` delegate method:

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if let touchView = touch.view {
            if touchView.isDescendant(of: view) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

So if the touch area is the subView, then the tap gesture will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks. What if I also want to add some gestures to subviews?

Comment: Can you refer to this answer for such case please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53990123/8447312 If that does not help you, I will try to improve my answer for multiple gestures