# Limit Gesture Recognizer to Only One Specific UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I have a UIView called `myView` on `myViewController`.  I have a UIGestureRecognizer called `swipeLeft` (code below) that detects when a user swipes left on it.

The problem is: `myViewController` recognises the same gesture on the whole screen and performs another action.  So I would like my app to perform `myMethod` when you `swipeLeft` in this particular area of `myViewController`, the area being `myView`.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                           action:@selector(myMethod:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeft.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[self.myView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

More details: I am using [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu) and `myViewController` is the right menu, so when it is visible, the whole view of `myViewController` recognises swipes in all directions.  I would like to change the recogniser in this particular UIView `myView`.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489780/exclude-subview-from-uitapgesturerecognizer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to add the swipe gesture to your view controllers header file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft;
```

If you look in DEMORootViewController.m, you will see this call:

```
self.rightMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightMenuViewController"];
```

This will call your awakeFromNib, and it's your first chance to do something. In here you will create that swipe gesture. You can not add it to your view yet though, because your outlets are not set at this point. The first time they are set is in viewDidLoad, so that's where you will add the gesture to your view. So add this to your view controllers implementation file

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:)];   
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.swipeView addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeLeft];
}

- (void)myMethod:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
    NSLog(@"Did swipe") ;
}
```

Finally you will need to tell the pan gesture in RESideMenu.m to fail whenever our swipeLeft gesture occurs. The way to do that is to add the following code to RESideMenu.m at line 220. That's at the end of the viewDidLoad method.

```
if ([self.rightMenuViewController isKindOfClass:[DEMOVC class]]) {
            DEMOVC *rightVC = (DEMOVC *)self.rightMenuViewController;
            if (rightVC.swipeLeft) {
                [panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:rightVC.swipeGesture];
            } } }
```

This is assuming your custom VC is called DEMOVC. You will also need to import your custom VC to RESideMenu.m like this:

```
#import "DEMOVC.h"
```

Please let me know if this worked out for you, and if there's something else I can help you with.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up.  I'm trying to do this step-by-step but I'm having a problem.  I am not using Storyboards by the way.  I am trying to implement this swipeLeft gesture in a UIView that is on my `rightMenu`, not my root view.  So I added the swipe gesture to my `rightSideMenuViewController.h` as you said the first thing to do.  As for the next line, I do not see it as I am not using Storyboards.  So where do I paste the `awakeFromNib` block of code?  In my `rightSideMenuViewController.h` or the first VC that appears, which is called `rootViewController`?

Comment: I apologise if it is a silly question but I wasn't too sure as you said 'add it to your view controllers implementation file'.  :)  Thanks!

Comment: I added it to my `rightSideMenuViewController.h` and I pasted the last `if` statement you said in `RESideMenu.h`, but now it is saying 'Use of undeclared identifier panGestureRecognizer'.

Comment: The point of awakeFromNib was to create the gesture as soon as possible so that your swipe gesture was set when the pan gesture was created. But I believe awakeFromNib is a storyboard thing. You could put it in `- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` of the rightSideMenuViewController.m instead (which will be called as soon as someone initialises the view controller).

Comment: As for the if statement, that needs to go just after the pan gesture recognizer has been alloced and initialized. Also change the class from DEMOVC to DEMORightSideMenuViewController.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  In the `if` statement in RESideMenu.m, I changed `DEMOVC` to `rightSideMenuViewController`, which is where `myView` is.  I changed `swipeGesture` to `swipeLeft` because it came up with an error.  But I still get the error **'Use of undeclared identifier panGestureRecognizer'** on the line `[panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:rightVC.swipeLeft];`.  :S

Comment: Yes, sorry about the swipeGesture, forgot to change it. 

I'm pretty sure the if statement is not in the right place yet, it should work (or at least compile) if you put it in the right place. It should be  near the bottom of `- (void)viewDidLoad` of RESideMenu.m, just after this line `UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(__panGestureRecognized:)];`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  I really appreciate it.  :)  It now works on two swipes I've made, swipeLeft and swipeRight, and I just changed the swipeDirection of both.  Thanks again!  :)